# TCheckBox in RAD Studio XE5 Mobile App

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, tcheckbox

I tried to use a CheckBox in a Firemonkey Mobile App. But when running the App I can't click on the CheckBox, e.g. it doesn't change it's IsSelected value.
Also if I try to handle the OnClick event I never receive this event.
On the same form I also use a TTMSFMXRating component. Most of the time it doesn't react when clicking on it. On an other form that TTMSFMXRating works without problems.
What do I do wrong ? I can't see any difference between these two forms (on both of them I also have some FireDAC DB access).
I also tried to generate a new FireMonkey Mobile App with just a CheckBox. But also there I can't change it's IsChecked value by clicking on it and don't receive any onClick events.
I would be happy for every hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCheckBox is not a standard component on mobile platforms so is not supported by RAD Studio.

Use TSwitch instead.

Comment: Protocol around here is to give credit for correct answers by marking the answer as such.